# JCL Error trying z/OS JSON parser programming example

Tags: c++, zos, jcl

I tried copying the c++ example as mentioned here -

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieac100/ieac1-cwe-json-prog.htm

However, I am getting the following JCL error when running on my system :

```
 IEF344I XC1CPLLE COMPILE SYSLIB - ALLOCATION FAILED DUE TO DATA FACILITY SYSTEM ERROR
 IGD17045I SPACE NOT SPECIFIED FOR ALLOCATION OF DATA SET
 SIEAHDR.H
 IEF272I XC1CPLLE COMPILE - STEP WAS NOT EXECUTED.
```

Here is a copy of my modified program :

https://gist.github.com/4349183c3ec6d223a0073b87b9c2da8b

Comment: Being a member for as long as you have, you should *really* know better than to post a "question" like this! Please re-read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [re-take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [re-read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry - can you be more specific? Whats wrong with the question?  I'd be happy to delete it or correct if I knew what was wrong with it.

Comment: I removed some information I believe was irrelevant.  Is that acceptable now?

Comment: Please post your entire JCL stream. The compilation step is trying to create SIEAHDR.H, which makes no sense for a compiler. Did you possibly forget DISP in your //SYSLIB concatenation? Remember, DISP default is NEW, not SHR or OLD.

Comment: Yep thanks @zarchasmpgmr thats the answer.  I originally posted the entire JCL stream but I was referenced to posting bad questions (see above) and my only guess was that my question had a lot of superfluous stuff in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JCL to which you provide a link contains a JCL error.  The SYSLIB DD of the COMPILE step has no `DISP` and thus defaults to `DISP=(NEW,DELETE,DELETE)`.  A status of NEW requires space allocation and none is provided, so you get the error in your question.  To fix this particular problem, I suggest coding `DISP=SHR` on the SYSLIB DD in the COMPILE step.

I recommend talking to your support staff about standard compile procedures, as most shops implement their own.